# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python

Im fairly new to Programming and started an Project. I wanted to programm an Parking meter with tkinter.

```
def Calculate():
    money = insert.get()
    try:
        float(money)
    except ValueError:
        error.config(text="Only Numbers!")
    else:
        hour = 0
        while (money > 0.4):
            if hour > 5:
                break
            else:
                hour +=1
                money-=0,4
        time.config(text=str(hour))
```

this is the piece of code where I get the error

```
line 13, in Calculate while (money > 0.4):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

I dont understand why I get this error and hope that I can find some help here.

Comment: You have not assigned the result of `float(money)` to any variable.

Comment: Thanks alot for the tipp, but now I get same error but with 'tuple' and 'float'. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Change line 4 to

```
money = float(money)
```

You convert your object, but forgot to save it!

Comment: btw There is no `casting` in python. Your example is of a conversion.